# Create AxisRange on Category Axis on amchart5

Tags: javascript, charts, google-maps-markers, stacked-bar-chart, amcharts5

I'm currently working on adding a position marker for a chart which is a stacked bar chart so it has category axis on xAxes. while i have done adding that position marker on other amcharts this chart's position marker(axisRange) is not moving a bit even if i give it a static value. Can anyone make it work for me in any chart if it's not possible in amchart.

I'm trying to make that axisRange move as the video progress. in fact i am making an axis range every second and removing old ones. that's how this dotted blue line at the start moves.
[image: I]

this is the live example

```
`https://codepen.io/danishaali9/pen/dygMeyz`
```

i want to give a static value and axis range to be shown on that value against Time(m) on xAxis

I tried swapping axes that is turning x into y and y into x axis but as i swap axes and the data also swaps with that.